# Multiple sets of GET variables in URL

Tags: php, html

So I have an iframe of a Flash application, which needs to have the GET parameters for the src as a link to a dynamically generated XML configuration file. This is generated using PHP and also has some variables passed through GET as well.

like this:

```
        <embed id="thingID" src="Thing.swf?license=xxxx&config=generateConfig.php?layoutType=grid&nColumns=2&nRows=4&"
            width="100%" height="100%">
        </embed>
```

The problem is that this doesn't work.
I think that "Thing.swf" is capturing the parameters that are meant to go to "generateConfig.php", but I cant find out how to separate these.

Working now. needed to `urlencode("generateConfig.php?layoutType=grid&nColumns=2&nRows=4");`
Thanks!!

Comment: If `generateConfig.php?layoutType=grid&nColumns=2&nRows=4` is supposed to be *one value* of the `config` parameter, it needs to be urlencoded.

Comment: You're also missing the ending doublequote.

Comment: Thanks, that example of doesn't have the last " but my version does.

@lafor it is one value of config. How do I urlencode it?

Comment: Just found http://au2.php.net/urlencode

Comment: It's customary to write a answer yourself, and accept it as correct, for future reference and to mark the question as closed.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the ending `"`

```
<embed id="thingID" src="Thing.swf?license=xxxx&config=generateConfig.php?layoutType=grid&nColumns=2&nRows=4&"
            width="100%" height="100%">
        </embed>
```

I would also opt to remove the extra `&`.